# Running Home Assistant (HASSIO) locally without an internet connection

Tags: raspberry-pi, local, home-assistant

I am new to Home Assistant and I currently have a disc image of the software installed on a Raspberry Pi 3b. I have managed to get this up and running successfully by connecting my PI to an internet connection via an ethernet cable and connecting my laptop to the same network wirelessly. The problem I am facing is that I wish to run this locally without an internet connection and simply connecting my laptop to the PI with the Ethernet cable does not seem to be working. I have tried looking around for support but I cannot seem to find much on the matter.

Comment: You are creating wrong conditions for the test. Both devices still have to have local IP addresses on the same network. Most likely they both(or some of them) do not have ip addresses configured because they do not see the same(any) dhcp server. For the test in question you could configure static addresses on both devices temporarily but it is probably not what you want in the end.

Comment: attempting to ping the static IP of the ethernet connection works, along with with 'homeassistant' host. if I try the static IP or the homeassistant.local in the URL with the port 8023, I cannot seem to get anything. I get more of a result with homeassistant.local though, as this says it refused to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Home Assistant's default port is 8123 not 8023.

If there is a direct connection between your laptop and the Raspberry Pi then the chance is high that mDNS won't not work. Thus, homeassistant.local is not reachable.

[Add a static IP address](https://github.com/home-assistant/operating-system/blob/dev/Documentation/network.md) for your Home Assistant host and your laptop.